# Why can't I get python to read RegisteredOwner registry key?

Tags: python, windows, registry

I ran this piece of code, which returned the Product Id reg key like it should:

```py
from winreg import *

def regstuff():
    for i in range(1024):
        try:
            RawKey = OpenKey(ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
            asubkey_name = EnumKey(RawKey, i)
            asubkey = OpenKey(RawKey, asubkey_name)
            val = QueryValueEx(asubkey, "ProductId")
            print(f"[Product ID]        {val}")
        except:
            pass
```

but then I changed "ProductId" to "RegisteredOwner" and now it doesn't return anything. It's only able to get the ProductId reg key. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: What if you remove the `try`/`except` which is counterproductive here because it hides from you what the problem is?

Comment: it then gives me `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` even though I can clearly see the RegisteredOwner key in registry

Comment: Why would it return anything? There's no `return` statement. Do you mean printing?

Comment: yeah i mean printing..,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going one level too deep on the `RawKey` path. Use this to access the sub-keys under `CurrentVersion`:

```
from winreg import *

def regstuff():
    for i in range(1024):
        try:
            RawKey = OpenKey(ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT")
            asubkey_name = EnumKey(RawKey, i)
            asubkey = OpenKey(RawKey, asubkey_name)
            val = QueryValueEx(asubkey, "RegisteredOwner")
            print(f"[Registered Owner]        {val}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

regstuff()
```

Edit: I'm also not sure why you need the range-based `for` loop, but I left it in just in case you had a reason for it... But here's how I'd do it instead of using a for-loop:

```
from winreg import *

def get_regkey(path, name):
    try:
        RawKey = OpenKey(ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), path)
        val = QueryValueEx(RawKey, name)
        print(f"[{name}]\t{val}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

get_regkey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ProductId")
get_regkey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOwner")
```